# how to prevent the elements inside the div from stacking when resizing the window?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, grid

i want to prevent the elements inside my main div from stacking on top of each other when window is resized.
[regular view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufav8.png)
[window resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nfm9.png)

```
<body>
<div class="calbody">
  <div class="top-body">
    <h1 class="body_name">CALCULATOR</h1>
    <div><input class="screen" type="text" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainbody">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <button type="button" class="b1 btn btn-danger">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" \>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">/</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap-5 ?

Comment: You can try changing `col-sm` to just `col` and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

yes, i am using bootstrap-5. It worked after changing col-sm to col.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to adjust the layout of the elements inside the div when the window is resized. You can also use flexbox or grid layout to keep the elements from stacking. Additionally, you can use JavaScript or jQuery to adjust the layout of the elements when the window is resized.

You can use the CSS property "flex-wrap" to prevent elements from stacking when resizing the window.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>


.container {
  display: flex; /* set the container to flex */
  flex-wrap: nowrap; /* prevent elements from stacking */  
}
```